# py2app KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval' when making Mac app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, py2app

I am trying to create a Mac app using py2app and Tkinter. The script is a simple one, it asks for an id and then uses pyodbc to get a record from the database. This is a much smaller version of the project that I am working on. I am using python3 and Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6

I have created a virtual env and have used the following terminal command:

```
py2applet --make-setup testfile.py
python setup.py py2app -A.   (App works fine in alias mode)
rm -rf dist build
python setup.py py2app --packages=PIL --includes=pandas
```

After the bundle is created I get the following error on running the app:

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'
  KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'
  KeyError:'pandas._libs.missing'
  KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'
  KeyError:'pandas._libs.interval'

How do I fix this? I have pandas 1.1.3 installed and have not made any changes in setup.py

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Did you find the solution of this?

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.coversion'